# Convert negative values to 0 values in attribute table

Tags: qgis, convert

I nedd to convert negatives values to 0 values in a column of the attribute table. I'm trying to use the field calculator with CASE function or coalesce, but I think I'm not writing the correct expression. How can I write it?
Example:

```
CASE 
WHEN "z" is <'0' THEN result = '0'
END
```

Comment: is your field text or numeric ? also are z and result field name ?

Comment: Case Statements will not change the underlying data it will only appear how you present it in your expression. We will need more information to answer this however. 1) Do you wish to alter the data in the table or just present it according to the expression. 2) What database are you using? This is the example from the QGIS docs: ` CASE WHEN "pop_density" < 50 THEN 'Low population density' WHEN "pop_density" >= 50 and "pop_density" < 150 THEN 'Medium population density' WHEN "pop_density" >= 150 THEN 'High population density'
END ` So in your case you need to do something like: `CASE WHEN "z" <

Comment: It is a numeric one, is the z I had extract from a dtm

Answer (score 3):

When using numerical values, you need to write your expression without singlequotes like this:

```
CASE WHEN "z" < 0 THEN 0 END
```

Singlequotes are used for strings.

Also you do not need `is` operator in this context. Not sure what you wanted to do with `result =`, but if its a field name you need to use doublequotes like `"result" =`. If you just want to overwrite `"z"`, there is no need to add `result =`. Just make sure to set `update field` in fieldcalculator.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to update the "result" field using the value from the "z" field the syntax is

```
CASE WHEN  "Z" <0 THEN 0 ELSE "Z" END
```

You get 0 for negative "z" value and keep the positive value the same (You need to select "update an existing field" and choose the "result" field)

Or

```
CASE WHEN  "Z" <0 THEN 0 END
```

to change the negative value in the "z" field to 0 and keep positive value untouched (You need to select "update an existing field" and choose the "Z" field)

Your error was to use quote around numeric value (they are needed for text) and to add result= before the return value